# DataStax C/C++ Driver for Apache Cassandra: Blob Conversion (GCrypt Crypto Key) Issue

Tags: c++, cassandra, blob, driver

I successfully add a **GCrypt Crypto Key (0x135aa10)** as a **CassBytes** structure to a Cassandra Cluster. See Cassandra C++ include: ***https://github.com/datastax/cpp-driver/blob/1.0/include/cassandra.h***.

```
// Create PSK Blob
CassBytes pskey_blob;
pskey_blob = cass_bytes_init((const cass_byte_t*) pskey, sizeof(pskey));

// Check that key BLOBED correctly
gcry_sexp_t tmpkey = (gcry_sexp_t)pskey_blob.data; //This correctly returns GCrypt Crypto Key (0x135aa10)

// Bind PSK Blob & Execute Statment
cass_statement_bind_bytes(statement, 0, pskey_blob);
future = cass_session_execute(session, statement);
cass_future_wait(future);
```

I then retrieve GCrypt Crypto Key from Cassandra as follows:

```
// Get Payload Secret Key
CassBytes pskey_blob;
cass_value_get_bytes(cass_row_get_column(row, 0), &pskey_blob);

if (pskey_blob.size != 0) {
  pskey = (gcry_sexp_t)pskey_blob.data;
  std::cout << "pskey: " << pskey << std::endl;
}
```

The blob data is returned within the CassBytes structure (pskey_blob.data) as 0x7f7fb00028a4 with the correct size of 8 (pskey_blob.size). It seems that Cassandra returns a HEX representation of my original unit8_t type GCrypt Crypto Key (0x135aa10) as HEX (0x7f7fb00028a4).

Does anyone know how to convert this from the Cassandra byte representation to the GCrypt Crypto Key?

Answer (score 1):

In the code above it looks like you're only copying the address of the `pskey` to Cassandra not the content of the key.

I've only superficially looked at the GCrypt docs, but it looks like you can print/scan the GCrypt S-Expr to a string buffer using `gcry_sexp_sprint()` and one of `gcry_sexp_new()`, `gcry_sexp_create()`, `gcry_sexp_scan()`.

Docs found here: https://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gcrypt/Working-with-S_002dexpressions.html#Working-with-S_002dexpressions

Disclaimer: I haven't compiled or tested this code. It's just a rough outline of what might work.

To INSERT the key might look like this:

```
size_t length = gcry_sexp_sprint(pskey, GCRYSEXP_FMT_DEFAULT, NULL, 0); // Needed to get the length
char* buffer = (char*)malloc(length);
gcry_sexp_sprint(pskey, GCRYSEXP_FMT_DEFAULT, buffer, length);

cass_statement_bind_string(statement, 0, cass_string_init2(buffer, length));
future = cass_session_execute(session, statement);
cass_future_wait(future);

free(buffer);
```

To SELECT the key might look like this:

```
CassString pskey_blob;
cass_value_get_string(cass_row_get_column(row, 0), &pskey_blob);
gcry_sexp_new(&pskey, pskey_blob.data, pskey_blog.length, 1); // Need to check the error here
```